# Read Browser/Client time from Http Servlet request header

Tags: java, javascript, http, servlets, http-headers

Is it possible to read the Browser(Client machine) time when a request is made to the servlet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe so. Unfortunately the HTTP [Date](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18) header is only sent for PUT or POST messages, and even then it's optional:

> Clients SHOULD only send a Date header
>   field in messages that include an
>   entity-body, as in the case of the PUT
>   and POST requests, and even then it is
>   optional. A client without a clock
>   MUST NOT send a Date header field in a
>   request.

If you have control of the client, you could (perhaps) encode it as a separate experimental HTTP header. Or add it as a GET parameter etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript and append the time to every request. Provided that javascript is enabled, you can add the following to your links:

```
link = link + "?date="+(new Date()).getTime()
```

You can do something similar, if you need timezone information. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript) may help.